# Core-bluetooth generates same UUID for different peripherals

Tags: ios7, core-bluetooth

IOS 7.0.4
Core-bluetooth generates the same UUID for two different devices. The devices are CSR1010 Developer Board. No bonding used.

Here is the log sequence

Just Device1 powered-on:

-- Peripheral found: "Device1"

-- Name: "Device1" UUID: DE5D6B14-E49A-8124-E4BC-5882734AE3F4

-- Connected to: "Device1"

Just Device2 powered-on

-- Peripheral found: "Device2"

-- Name: "Device2" UUID: DE5D6B14-E49A-8124-E4BC-5882734AE3F4

-- Connected to: "Device2"

This logs are coming from

didDiscoverPeripheral ( first two )

didConnectPeripheral (last one )

Any help?

Comment: Don't those devices have the same MAC address? Do both of them show up at the same time if you scan, for example, with the LighBlue app?

Comment: Even the LightBlue application sees just one device.

Comment: Are you sure they have different MAC addresses?